# Reinstalling Microsoft.BingWeather package

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, powershell

So I was uninstalling windows default apps (Maps, xbox, get started, edge...) and also deleting their folders in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps (shouldn't have done that, I know).

However while uninstalling I accidentally removed weather app (Microsoft.BingWeather) and deleted its folders from previously mentioned location. I would like to get it back but can't find a way to do that

I tried installing it from the Store as it is listed there but without success, writing add-appxpackage command in PoweShield did nothing (because deleted folders). I don't know what to do now, maybe get same files/folders and then try to use PowerShell command to add them? Guyz plz hulp!

USING: Win10 Enterprise x64, Version 1607 Build 14393.693

Comment: Are the deleted folders in Recycle Bin?

Comment: No, I deleted them completely.

Comment: Do you have access to another Windows 10 computer that you could copy the relevant folders from? Maybe a friend or family member has Windows 10 and would let you copy the Weather files?

Comment: @SirAdelaide I managed to get the files from my friends computer. I've got them from _C:\Program Files\WindowsApps_ that contained followring folders:

**Microsoft.BingWeather_4.18.37.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe**
**Microsoft.BingWeather_4.18.37.0_neutral_split.language-lt_8wekyb3d8bbwe**
**Microsoft.BingWeather_4.18.37.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe**
**Microsoft.BingWeather_4.18.37.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe** .

I ran the script in Power Shell that installed the Weather app, and I can see it now in Start menu. However when I open it, nothing happens. No GUI nothing. **CONTINUE** 1/2

Comment: @Sir **2/2** I think the app can't find the source folders/files or maybe I'm missing some files from other directories. In the STORE the app is shown as installed. Any thoughts what can be missing or what should I try?